# Converting byte array to an image

Tags: c#

I am trying to get an image from a smart card reader. It came with a sample C# solution which displays card's information and the cardholder's portrait. Unfortunately, the portrait never shows up. It's actually written to a file with following content:

```
 jP  
‡
   ftypjpx     jpx jp2 jpxb   1rreqÿ  ÿ  €  +@                  ‹jp2h   ihdr  >   î    Scolr    HLino  mntrRGB XYZ Î     1  acspMSFT    IEC sRGB             öÖ     Ó-HP                                                 cprt  P   3desc  „   lwtpt  ð   bkpt     rXYZ     gXYZ  ,   bXYZ  @   dmnd  T   pdmdd  Ä   ˆvued  L   †view  Ô   $lumi  ø   meas     $tech  0   rTRC  <  gTRC  <  bTRC  <  text    Copyright (c) 1998 Hewlett-Packard Company  desc       sRGB IEC61966-2.1           sRGB IEC61966-2.1                                                  XYZ       óQ    ÌXYZ                 XYZ       o¢  8õ  XYZ       b™  ·…  ÚXYZ       $   „  ¶Ïdesc       IEC http://www.iec.ch           IEC http://www.iec.ch                                              desc       .IEC 61966-2.1 Default RGB colour space - sRGB           .IEC 61966-2.1 Default RGB colour space - sRGB                      desc       ,Reference Viewing Condition in IEC61966-2.1           ,Reference Viewing Condition in IEC61966-2.1                          view     ¤þ _. Ï íÌ  \ž   XYZ      L    V P   Wçmeas                            sig     CRT curv           
     # ( - 2 7 ; @ E J O T Y ^ c h m r w |  † ‹  • š Ÿ ¤ © ® ² · ¼ Á Æ Ë Ð Õ Û à å ë ð ö û
%+28>ELRY`gnu|ƒ‹’š¡©±¹ÁÉÑÙáéòú&/8AKT]gqz„Ž˜¢¬¶ÁËÕàëõ !-8COZfr~Š–¢®ºÇÓàìù -;HUcq~Œš¨¶ÄÓáðþ
+:IXgw†–¦µÅÕåö'7HYj{Œ¯ÀÑãõ+=Oat†™¬¿Òåø2FZn‚–ª¾Òçû     %   :   O   d   y      ¤   º   Ï   å   û

'
=
T
j

˜
®
Å
Ü
ó"9Qi€˜°Èáù*C\uŽ§ÀÙó


&
@
Z
t
Ž
©
Ã
Þ
ø.Id›¶Òî    %A^z–³Ïì   &Ca~›¹×õ1OmŒªÉè&Ed„£Ãã#Ccƒ¤Åå'Ij‹­Îð4Vx›½à&Il²ÖúAe‰®Ò÷@eŠ¯Õú Ek‘·Ý*QwžÅì;cŠ²Ú*R{£ÌõGp™Ãì@j”¾é>i”¿ê  A l ˜ Ä ð!!H!u!¡!Î!û"'"U"‚"¯"Ý#
#8#f#”#Â#ð$$M$|$«$Ú%   %8%h%—%Ç%÷&'&W&‡&·&è''I'z'«'Ü(
(?(q(¢(Ô))8)k))Ð**5*h*›*Ï++6+i++Ñ,,9,n,¢,×--A-v-«-á..L.‚.·.î/$/Z/‘/Ç/þ050l0¤0Û11J1‚1º1ò2*2c2›2Ô3
3F33¸3ñ4+4e4ž4Ø55M5‡5Â5ý676r6®6é7$7`7œ7×88P8Œ8È99B99¼9ù:6:t:²:ï;-;k;ª;è<'<e<¤<ã="=a=¡=à> >`> >à?!?a?¢?â@#@d@¦@çA)AjA¬AîB0BrBµB÷C:C}CÀDDGDŠDÎEEUEšEÞF"FgF«FðG5G{GÀHHKH‘H×IIcI©IðJ7J}JÄKKSKšKâL*LrLºMMJM“MÜN%NnN·O OIO“OÝP'PqP»QQPQ›QæR1R|RÇSS_SªSöTBTTÛU(UuUÂVV\V©V÷WDW’WàX/X}XËYYiY¸ZZVZ¦Zõ[E[•[å\5\†\Ö]']x]É^^l^½__a_³``W`ª`üaOa¢aõbIbœbðcCc—cëd@d”dée=e’eçf=f’fèg=g“géh?h–hìiCišiñjHjŸj÷kOk§kÿlWl¯mm`m¹nnknÄooxoÑp+p†pàq:q•qðrKr¦ss]s¸ttptÌu(u…uáv>v›vøwVw³xxnxÌy*y‰yçzFz¥{{c{Â|!||á}A}¡~~b~Â#„å€G€¨
kÍ‚0‚’‚ôƒWƒº„„€„ã…G…«††r†×‡;‡ŸˆˆiˆÎ‰3‰™‰þŠdŠÊ‹0‹–‹üŒcŒÊ1˜ÿŽfŽÎ6žnÖ‘?‘¨’’z’ã“M“¶” ”Š”ô•_•É–4–Ÿ—
—u—à˜L˜¸™$™™üšhšÕ›B›¯œœ‰œ÷dÒž@ž®ŸŸ‹Ÿú i Ø¡G¡¶¢&¢–££v£æ¤V¤Ç¥8¥©¦¦‹¦ý§n§à¨R¨Ä©7©©ªª««u«é¬\¬Ð­D­¸®-®¡¯¯‹° °u°ê±`±Ö²K²Â³8³®´%´œµµŠ¶¶y¶ð·h·à¸Y¸Ñ¹J¹Âº;ºµ».»§¼!¼›½½¾
¾„¾ÿ¿z¿õÀpÀìÁgÁãÂ_ÂÛÃXÃÔÄQÄÎÅKÅÈÆFÆÃÇAÇ¿È=È¼É:É¹Ê8Ê·Ë6Ë¶Ì5ÌµÍ5ÍµÎ6Î¶Ï7Ï¸Ð9ÐºÑ<Ñ¾Ò?ÒÁÓDÓÆÔIÔËÕNÕÑÖUÖØ×\×àØdØèÙlÙñÚvÚûÛ€ÜÜŠÝÝ–ÞÞ¢ß)ß¯à6à½áDáÌâSâÛãcãëäsäüå„æ
æ–çç©è2è¼éFéÐê[êåëpëûì†ííœî(î´ï@ïÌðXðåñrñÿòŒóó§ô4ôÂõPõÞömöû÷Šøø¨ù8ùÇúWúçûwüü˜ý)ýºþKþÜÿmÿÿ   res    resc€ €    jpch   jplh  "®jp2cÿOÿQ /     î  >                       ÿR    ÿ\  PXX`XX`XX`XXXPPXÿd  Kakadu-v6.3.1ÿd Kdu-Layer-Info: log_2{Delta-D(MSE)/[2^16*Delta-L(bytes)]}, L(bytes)
 -45.0, 6.0e+002
 -46.3, 7.0e+002
 -47.2, 8.2e+002
 -48.5, 9.9e+002
 -49.4, 1.2e+003
 -50.2, 1.6e+003
 -51.5, 2.0e+003
 -52.6, 2.6e+003
 -53.8, 3.5e+003
 -55.2, 4.8e+003
 -56.2, 6.5e+003
 -57.8, 9.0e+003
ÿ 
    !% ÿ“Ï•€Í’*;%í#WúÓxðž·SéÊè­M°&ê•>•VŠœn
Àkpt€–ŒŽÿ3¶c€ñ@v/¯*Ôý0À-hñ "ÈÁ>’‰õ½€€Õ€ç¹Eò´pcXÞÐMð°È”|µ*¸ÊaÛŽf€€€€Ã¥ Q&¾LúÚÊ€ÆQÄ€€ñ`~; £d­`žÈÃ}8ã Éˆ¼gå=õ Ùß´^Ž·°%¬¨õ*ÐÙ€€€Ç#ûœ!—Í±\b‚â%$á€}ÁÊâŠàÏá€»ÄÄÊÉoí?v€ñ °àLˆ=d[›â B Ð"ÌÖ&ÜuÄrñ`e\š!ÿ~÷:€€ÇÄj>¡Ò 5má[ò£
Fƒµ²r–…Wyª}[Á"X•—Žø~‹Y>OÀ‰](h®ÑžáÖ¾²x û%ŽLMÂ$&qÁ—<×=œt¶É’ë‚ôã>
¦o[Î‹Øâ2€L›­Á“‚dKubˆ¼rñ<V(;íb2G=ˆÑdÃPÄbÂFû™mÃÍh¤Ì”›$+#ˆ©N€÷¼ª0À©0ë§îqKN ™áð YûØÉûØrçG÷®õ8
ïÍ•§ÃÑ-—JÖõX½
^YÃ¼vÛµ_ú.* ÷Ä–NÁrœHFxv(¤ÛDsœPíHðª(u)Mn<€€€€€ á RK EÀ˜?¬…;Cðý4˜-L¹ÿ.»”þ·˜ùåÍ4ý‹ÖOÎ2àä_Ê=Ç£Zù‰6Èâ§{âG-@Àš"[ÿWÇ‘”ß¸®Ëß„î>+,âÍ²Šl¨Ï¿Ë(ieQC¦É#¬ô®/Œå)a’pÄpƒ{âõô¡HÐÉˆ’|„õ±%¹´÷^£à‹Ë€p@‡xÁÓ1À7†¯Û!êŽ"­Ö¶Hƒ`*?±fÇ1¥mÈ#×Í&0îx2cškÛ8AÆO;‰â ÃÇÉÓ€ÁÌ–ŸÇoøàeGÿ-Gì7ÈñàŠRÒtn‡]dÑº:„Êþª·áñ’€Ë€Åbuj£ Ñgã QWôî3ˆë¯õôÃ ¶LÊªA$<A+WûÕ=d×¹ÎÕà²¢`€ÇQŽŸ  fV“tÔÕí@OÅuhn‘{?¸Ìí0©„‘a¯áÒð($Ëæ«çr”`‰}¶½‡03;ø  +“¥YÜÈ_ã—a!¡ól'}sÑº~ÊÄ A×¾l1;¼“òôé ùþSçÐ¤ˆÎm‹Êßœ—‚|B×|k•³rý¨>Õuâ#]°…ßbëdÆ±Èµ”Ä:ˆ!tþ²Q¦iÙ©zd¨ÓÄ8PÖu¬´F®‚ráƒäzpêùX…€DN„\À.Õìï8…w<œˆIæ‡ÿVw§ž˜¤[!JÐTl,xµŽºšÄ[$³›B«”r¶¥ÕSœfÑxmÉa„¯Kðþ7YfFÙã«1‰–‚àTd $¼FæC<¯Nb:æ¡Íöôí©bÛätŠ{g¦i&h;þ°Âc~ÏžÃçMÖ56gÎ9L$µòÝôe^Ù²N¼þ|½ÈÇá`"ž»mÍ&á¢ÓjuORÂ+îµ yFÑ¯ÆruÝA$wØ”œG{{“ ‡óAtF¤›o°ïLQÔïó»’
éþñOH€eðreò<Á;ÃSŒ
š³Låâ]ÖÈ­QU
UÀL]i£œúóŽsÈ¢E*!wÇløn[»å“5Àðé¹UNAŽ’y±;n4 uUóSžj¨Ý×÷pWƒúuñ7á º,&NÚÊ§õE¶œ«>Aå9®VG†ó»Už&E#Lm¶ZK5ZõÒhÅñ¶DùK-Lûµ{N°n.¢H¤5õ¢VcÊz@b¼!>ì‘|ÛÔÞ+RQº¯0«Îm|Anw   ›}ì1h«Q/f_Xì
¶O;A§sHH°Û¢Ÿz{Ð·à6Jj ‹jÎ5.Š’„Ï0ëÌœVÚÛ‹†!e€€€€€€€ÁÒàT —Móz&#?*¿«yöY£»·ò§ @ÆáÓc.¦.Íãì?–y=ÉûìÓ€WID`ˆf&*ŒwP6ezÔjÐ:Hõ«Œ¹’ÂÞˆëÖªŽð$lh+:ë4÷Ë4jàëh/±ôL^¹N„y96\Õá8?*€ø‚dº¾{RžÅøï¹!È[Gp®žq-ÐÇÅ’ ¨oÔÀñ4¯¶îã˜8õL…‚Y.àI’”–~iF£e 8˜Û'5j=³DXón eçÄ•
Áxz÷GlŠ(æòãeò+‘¯×DÕÝ=Ð¬¶¼øŽŽÈì&S€Ç
$Ñ€€€ˆ·'¡Ò€­©Ê™¥¹žYÁS/‹•)“Ng0 åÚLÅæXÓ\qñœ ß’[91yy˜66Q.ð÷\ñé“wÏñVdèÍ¬ˆJÅzÍ,€j+š|eR””.ÐUÒRÞÛ2;âñ\páE³p}>uê³dP‡a±<¥-ÃçY‚–µÎ£±·¾ç3z¸˜ñàÈ†ÞÍÁS»p'6&@
]jwŸO"…âî÷ØŸw ìö]‡gS“õÉ·ªñèv©6p
»à;ø&À™eMªFXL]„Mä!EGÈ¤6"ñ¬`”Àr´~ ìÉbÁVÆºr°ÎÏrà£<G€ŽNr>Wÿ€ÅZø»?´÷¢´—5\¤W¼|#?°°C%ô¸Ûê9ðþsµVÌ“.YžYdpý
9ìœê$à·-ÕËó2v)ï#Úò&u€Ç
 Ã?›ÚÑÕ¡P‡7©ôiá6üÅ-ë»šèJÖ²ø‚äÜ/T?XÎ[#»Ð„9¶kU7H-Þ2š(Ú´‹âuœPoå„áMqF.}îùãva»GúkËá·~¹™WPa ÃHü÷(¥ã©G+Vj!>DÉòà8Ù³?{÷¼pÌx9ªHà¬ÿno!’è®r×—œj½úF°àÈg^‡ád\–í"Tÿ«ÉFr1ôž™÷G+ú†ËhÔ¸Õ@fáŒ¨ÌTp„Šöè&ÕSbØ"[ñ9U±‘¤™î%o·²hCG¶¶mmš€ÞE»
[’ïq[€t¤ˆh®\k¿Ó¯´åX¼Dòâ‡ ~GšA)³àýløÆÏ·”æôjCä2zuÏ ßÑbp.×1µÁ,úK±Ç…XEÞ«4>f²ÒWL…‚£#HžŒsÈ¿8 ÖjF+•Q²KS÷+àtu‡$ñÓ–<¤×áô`S¦—†Fvgˆ¿ )»Ç©=V@:Ü%MÈi|³ŒÌ$þ¯è@Ò¹½3E×lfˆ·®ËLHøW&Ã¨_8­Ãð–§Ivt–¦¼¬rí£}·i=<Ñ×Úâ¹F>€é¶¾14¨0ík|aièˆƒ».õD1kœy7öQ-°Ò©¶*öf=„|Œx@bÃŠ»|ÓgÔàaEÅg×›'ÀicgzhÄ¯Ý‚tDg†³˜Ò]”X1Ì
²ìE-Ÿ\/?}kä@õ:«N“6šÂ—êÒ*®2ˆ    í÷¢Ë€°Ê†¼t5569í›ÓD=[Fö„Ñ§1£ë>ŽÕ:Ík þ©:;!…œºÌeì¿›   x ŒÑ§ë÷úÿ®§Ç¶»ÜòÿF™pÔÉòkJíRâÂÞñî
^:KÜ=!àYoay«E™Þz†­dÄòœÞ
¬ñŽ ƒ²ŠL?WÓµüt…¤‘ž²W1:†Õ{Ë y cµ¯È½œ/"›Ân(–DÖt.3[q¿€˜+3¾¹wFË`5s1ÜâÈÄ÷ê [rš`ùçO$þ}ïËÛ0¨µÍ[  E©«ÞIY¶YR£¤)” Ô¼Ò"j
ãc'ÄT:â×;)V|dðsUy*=Üóô\M}1þ›³¦”¶ªYÃ«ªÙt–ô÷ÈñkÞ™êCÌñÇí9;÷šÞ(÷Ü =ëšá¶á@LîRºN¬³téQ^ÀÿzÍ”ÏÛ°ƒR¿Î_$Á#‚÷¸^þ©ªÂùöÞÌ¶dê“=Í!¥;ñm™¢K*0+P“-žH;kØè/DF {RÀB£ÕÕã|‹Œh¹¤”qàÍ4ÂŠ[»í²V¬
ÔÒèT&"Ñ±\g
cÐl‡òç#ÑÈ¹‘À{švÇD– ÓD%É­[K:i M)K’úCH‹×n(ÍŠõ
ï²XAÚ ¶ü^„jjŽÔ|’ûR‘c×™f1C/ßPxŒá3YœÎjˆøínª„_¢ý:ÔÐt¼E<ÒK5XÖÙpƒ†Û9Ö!ð–j5§Ì’žÂü¥OàÂR%ûAOŽ<¯ãÆÈ”ùõ] ð’=Re¶ì¡SUMÒ
]e1°Š„5ÆHGšZ£mYÐÑ|ÇT+s ~œOQÜ–©’çLJOpÊ/îjcC¿4XÈL®9KäÇr0å\Är“È_Í'mídëZ´Ÿ™ßxMó
Žºû%Û×RTÎø&>À›á³.Þ1RÀ®YÈs¥Ë‡Üš…b¤AÌ>ÓÚ2‘Eèº±µà¶ñNŒ'RbspBå£×1ÿbª?2­m) €ì¨µ`§ëÑ4W/ w›£Ñ$wœx®"AQ©ôÌâ/@øúÖºøÑÑ
Ù1b'GßHtQ­5ƒl=7ÙO|ó«7[$æ9:±âP7¶-ëÁPYDÐ(P„§|
ñ[rißU¬ºá€„Ñ|.×T}T C&ö~ CÛº;Âé¨ÿzˆ*zÞðbS\-«Žƒ*h>Õý"Òã)=ÌMr«/•H¾T$-\C¸ö¶<Ÿ÷&ƒEšr™îLºÒ?3Œ÷
üÁÒÊœ1
Òv!.DŽü¸2Ë–«ct ²Ñæl;ÂÇÆyfb‰Bí¶Û<[[Ûæµy×ÁÇñ
–Ò;×ÓñNhº&Y³lfqú„¯
€Oƒ›+ï»ìßkx¶Gªô"6ký$b´ZËêš–õ™ ™Ý¼ÈŠy¦“Ú±Í8Dµ?êAgc´Úý0ÂxÊEWØ^n¢ÎŒ­Ø­ÂvÎ¡³ƒ5˜‚J‹ui7Âh9ÎZï?œJXu%=Ùè_8:óÎ­.Sažü“-Øiðh³ŒW­ët8xçèÀ}î\÷$¡Ú˜å‹#ÈNÆ>•³­ýí«».ê†€€€€€€€€€€ÀÕ sBÕÖ2Å×å›((=Äù|<&MjÌýJÓÉ;íùÈúd–ž†ØBƒGæ{žÒ#|½ÇxuGêÙàò½‡úDGp…Y”ôÅ»¯6ÅBˆPêP;ÁÛcnôO Õ™¢—,yo( XC 9ÓqTâ˜ºA5ÖŸtÃÖ(·x¦§Û–°­¡L€€€€€€Ã†€°æ+™³äÜ4<»HsÍŠ·t¤ £5Xêy0F ¯y+Ñù cnßKäGñTø°± Z#_uækõ}wÒ y¤D÷£ëgÛÜÆ
b-›9ØGS°G>¹P›ØòôæÂdf"„RßHå0›«*4É Î„0£-OÂÒ_2S%çx~G2ïdÚ>]Æ¸4)Ê/é-™v~¶…N>Æý´Ó‰Nh¾|BÐÚyÄ^»gkò±H|]!;Óú
ýlSë"q@ÕJ‘ô¦gþ%ŒOÆ ›®ÝÊØ(èÀxA|ð÷kÔÇÜˆµ#UìñÓW¹ÑÀ‡YÕ¹*yÿlVÍd2©H»”¶ž®›`Ë|c2m‘6¼ÿGNš3‘#CÆ±g¼î‘åRQhRmâ %÷=“¥ÏïÖéâf‰_rñ§¹Òè·×À{CfhåTWèYT*Íöàâ›ººÓ-íPÞ+ðœYžÜæØ‘
vê)ÎcÏ^såúíñ l/ù<3Jª…§«†‹j‚Fc"TiÌÆ”¼ï¤ž_z~}ùNƒ¯<–¶{¦Ê¤U×LÚƒ©ÿD.gõ÷wÏËµRú.mÉ_(S:“èEÕ†Cã+ªï,ß´‰…?WËÝ7úÛ#½A¾!ÿEÌÚç ÷¤Ó6SÇîÀï{<IûÒ{€€€€áºTÝ(ô}%TRd—`¡{•W¾ÀÓÃ©Ø®Øýb;¾·e@F7uØ=›ÙW·E?»Çáf-Ë È¶³S÷ÍàE‚JÅ²­M©ëÓîµ+Œû¨¶Y«^£LÕÂpýï;ÔyïÔ–ç³×¡äq?cI$'E/È}Rw;ºÙ÷=òGVL¤{øG{¼Ú™´Þ«¡ö9bZJ%„ç†/_ÙÖÀ‘ÂøîÒNžV
ŒÂí«Æ
©m«ÔÉžTÿ@=pHå|jHxgg˜Œ:w0½‚
P”Òq´&KHúÍå“ Cl¨M‹.Xâº«/¶õC…¯&¾;`lãÜÜÆ®Ó¥‘RÇ'MËeo(Çƒ_3ŒŸ]àý›Þ‡‚KàÙTØOÃù!— ˜œÜ+kÃÕÐ¤fØ`@åîÖ7J¶ß_4À*"ÃK f!ßI¢7D=‚‘Y/Ý¬#±w$—Ž¯¬ªç<ßDÇAÔ­?³¸_úÑf'l÷4_ß§à
}«€€‰4êKoxsÓ(¾˜Ub–VÕâC€¾ùÏœ½IœaÔ=siH˜·*€ÈŠèòš]ù@ütÆ†¿I°¹Qm
ŽB §Ü#ÜØw²‡†Ùä‰º
°Ÿq¿­"ŸÓI@Fx‘ÿ~~rèc1Âa}î5Ýö!~[ÁÆE’ËæÄìKD*dË‹Â"°&ª½œ ó¡nMñØ™N‘mí"ôâÞÍ äË\ê:K€å½ks!MÔæà¹‘›‘<HØj6œ»ìF¢ü‰F¦°W9«gŒ‚~ln‚’w’ð  ðè®;ØV5ÿVÛ¿®n1ï7Îÿ-fÑœ¹(}”â×( ù1ÅFQ_œ+
±kÉJ’H.U„Ù«ÖÏòM
©qµ”ü\ho  °/ÈR9Dæ»¦S¬ñn†h&ª”£â…&-lò‚êxêžh0Ì—…ìF×À¥ò oøÛ±Æ@Íº=ù§ì±#ÕnL+¤dµ~èÉ•ÖÊü.gÂqúÜ]ÒUÐ;3çöEr{ÃÏ>k­PŽjç4µn”E‡y©°9OšHÈÎ=cš '¨ð’YûÉ—¸Œ€¿(ûÉŸÚ€@Z`å³eDÿ_e`ÆyºÕœœj}ò@7«&3ªõÚŽ–ç>qB|ÍwŽëäö¢…Ö‰:Xw[XŠRk›p™ó£h‘ãjˆ\}m˜Œº3wá›,sQ¹Ëž‡Úëñ´·øM®h¡¿”q*Õ}íÞÈß;=ùåªù
oi|0» ”ND4&a;X€’ÿZ÷8f²Zý9Ìä€—kÀ~µPÈþy“•cºVˆõÔX•Òi5ÎÐJ`TÙ*¹ý¤¤ŒÁÚÇ|ýÇ 7CÑâ`4#ýžñrš}i Ì¶~|-´`g¾âOSÿ3
H­.5þÒ>‚À„*)íêé2åÿKòó9FBf2ÏkOâ9ö  æ}^›«äë~C5—@ò]@J¢SNo-iƒ°ó8¥Šv…V§È.6Sø‚|ÏÑ’#8À™Q†žZ|ÔC¶kcM#qzú)ôh~Dþ¿ÔJärÍç9ò0òªLL˜Šˆ»¹tßøÂdÍ-Éý>Â™§†Ó(F®†JÁjUŽ‰CÛ@’OZ@¼(£T…žÊæ]ß;^_:üÊÃºRR@oú9 öµ¹­Ã¬¥â(O{IVR€Ñ<Âµ+‚  Áêˆ91(XËËÔê#Aú`ÀÚÆ~Ô:±®ûYRµ`ï üM
¥ƒÖ\7Æpã799¥Ùo™.™Bwœ“õâY|ê
üD9DKq ¿ mº"{øý´Qí! ‚f³*kÌ¶¿   â†&¹SÂ–î4X‘âÓÒu‡,$Q¬Dæ/¡9%@dê“H">éiÉ%þ^îÝóÕKª‹Q7›¶JxÓ¿g¯XI¦¿ôºibÞ¨ö¨àÕAJ½„¸®ìë2iœ{‘lT/¬”€ÖåØ·:ÆHtc¿ÇÃDUë×e æò;èªT,ðDË§ÛŸ¼®¹rAvË°øè¼¦ï"·1-‡ð”‚F«`¾Âcl5§Å·<³œ‡w{—¤öÖWŒ!
eŸóë%¦åMêšŠÀ2Ïç…¾äÊ¡èæd4ÐŒìãd›Óì`…|3…Ü ÆL®ü”y'N•oO™ã8"N„6d?
-Sb›ÁÒÞmÉŒ<4q'þ›ë)?åUðM‰§uç‡ÖYµ3=è7Vaèñ,ýï½à´ L_QÆ:`q_`*¬îpÇ3ªtPu\:j^W`³ýJ#Ó1‰41ø^ æM„N(‹#»0Rjˆ8jãúc5“É:Ö¬U/ |åñÎ*5Ðu„ÿ5PÝÊ}#ƒú@p9QK<Iµ<óójó:»¹™2wJomç
À‚_(²r<kÎ.
w¹ÅbFf;Bw%‰;>Uqt(zºëIô\`5Î
÷¬”B¸­Q’ß)Má3±+Œ| 
Ù¬·tÊŠ"ÓÁ–ïƒåºÛä&³ú»¸!¶ H·A³»;.ª¨¸þC¿4eþ‚ª½ AÀÇq!½wPN„šåZ½€bÕfž›ŽûÊ^ˆÅk¦ Âc–³6ÖÈ™%á‘1ZK/{Æ×g%iÛ‘¤ö‚³`h±ÍOX^»{"ÉÆ°GZü%Ù7AžŒdó‹ÅÚY÷—­X­ºxµö ñ­˜ïnú ex¦t,ðÃd-/¥Ü>]*š®éîy!µ[ðËb¬Ob,PãÀž¶iò8ÅvãM"¦†šÐ€p@ÉyLŠ{å#ÓLNö!—È1x§Ã_¦þ{¡O¨(M¶$ðl¦‹J(0UÿêäöÔ KÀt@gì…|Ù&Xš=<Cã°2bV*ˆ?wà.¶ãû{þÀœD3Ý|ê‡Ô\KþµXöìk “Už;lw~ê
¤­Mú™ð|Bœœ…ZIuIgEÙÉÔ=Ž
]ØâOM Yi25ÌzÞ´üEže{µÙ›$ÛNçÖ¢ï¤b*9f)Îùc¿46   í«züÖÐËÅÁ æÃ«g5«ýok´X³WUyÇ}(·Áös\Î-Éÿ^×MÄÖª  8¨B¿ªFçŽÈ©dš‰ÞÆ·žâEðN‚­’}:ÔÔ/¼?n"É¿É´!Ñ25}ã*˜§F½ÚHG±»t¤+xjŒµ‰_°šþ9è¯x‰Íý~+Aû[úr=qJ6çæ%H«¯g«µè€U²ìº +(*OÁã P‹’'?êòy¥”™èdø¼sÉ¯H>:¯q©}2ï,•§©œ†Ñ©âßÜOÅY   UÏÞ­ z[“ê¤0:!©¿4ÀN¯Ké—¹â0±% râûŸe`¢ø Kgåòyó¾·µ¿”\–O^Ç{ï^Z;Âé…=<‡¿ZÞ¶õ´LgÞë6^–î·P-‘/W†`…ÜÌ ýM3Oãú>ÿ'Ä8Š(Y  ¹Ör+äþ:/¢
Ôhû˜æ@7x9i™XÐK7!²\;x$-t ¬ûZ’ÒŸ=Efõ¹C½,¿Ñ~.ÚúÙLq\ ŠmŸ[Ø. PüaM{ZÔmÀlÃÇ_K«iï‰ÍGEV˜ÞfÑ«!ŒeýžSs)ÃÂ|.Š‚ÜßFì‰hïùÍJƒ-·Álk9>s1™Á]3Sš}Ã$ÏÆkIÍ­ÅÕˆ2Œ,oH  ˜€?Õ]½(Gq¹¤NóÚÑn´‡OŒèdpŠl¬
QN¤&õàWlˆª„ª<‚6…«1ýð¼ñw¤y@ŸÀÖ|N·Ïìë1ü†%5Ö£ŠŒš¢Ó?R*$Ù S)Ò¤ŠµÞ°ÌºÄRQd”÷.é
4€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€Ðôºž×iæ/ÕÅlLÈS×ÆX‰ØI+ÔéÑPË-°¤HÅ¦¡•Óÿ,Ëk.ëÙ48`ñ³p¤91þî»AÙÂ˜¯ hÊ.üpgÌ£§Ä/Šá3‹«xóÊ0Œ­Ö*è9 —§ÀpÄLÁ+7cfâ³)ƒg—E§ßdª6>W©õÙó€€€€€€€€€ññ¾ÓÖ—ˆqö”~õý2¦&»€åü¶.©ê2sLÃW˜d¸–²] úûâL”·Tò«$ÛÃ=!áG2ØÌW¸Û 0jÐ½I_Í—Ün%¿  UÙŠ^…H.“ÄšÓÍ>X5Ñ¦¨1<9YŽ= /´jÈ 
çw)ùÈÐHóXˆ—yCÊÕ+j*ËR ¾{ŒÖ«ü
–K&?Ýµ/åŽt¤aÑÜ,z.¨A6lÊ<˜ýÍÄírx×InðV¢¦~Q (’å´ùsœNñhŽ~¬ÖìàºÀ1ïÑ/†*ÏlP½ˆ¥3øW0ÀÂâç2ÚáR¥Mh›üï‡º›´‡Ö‡ë‡6¯u•DMÐzØ;‘4?Ü§*šÄ€á3t¤þpE@öMzâ"éZhì™¿‡¤¸«1Jr×€Í‰ÃÈÉâYB?Êò¿+æÂTìSåVW®Ý§ þ®S   ê-Él~Ìí#Ùá€7u®R˜…ŠnÉÔùÃŸë    !\¾<¾t6¶¯ýû!}ïñ©Òå°DsØ<¦A „ ºrZî×­ä0Mr/vë
Ü’*Ùˆ¦O<1‹dp¦ÛPAš©“Hò]›|Ž¾¾8'oÏ\áËÚ$^C÷²ù¾ãyÂÕr: ¼&#ÞÆ3ó    ûÇã¾Ð8Œ-rÈcãìm¢ÖÑ‰‡ý—§Z’»ùMRL\ÁgªóOx…(}noîÖuÙo$x.WÆÖx£Ö|\¨WÆÔ;3´¶‹é±éŠ„
 £‰…gÝáõ29$‚DùÝ
zŠ»õ†ÑÄ^uˆ{:Y˜Êç±Rl*aw–øGôdŒ*8wÖ5ÁÑœ°åÜM§no—iõÑÎäé]†ÔWY×
TÞà4ÖH‰5„|ãÎ"æZl|kŽþ²sÖÙºš0˜(´GÐH‘AUØ€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€ÿÙ
```

It has some line with following text:

```
Copyright (c) 1998 Hewlett-Packard Company  desc       sRGB IEC61966-2.1           sRGB IEC61966-2.1
```

The code:

```
cmdSelect = new APDUCmd(0x00, 0xA4, 0x00, 0x00, new byte[] { 0x3F, 0x00 }, 0x00);
cmdResponse = cardOri.Transmit(cmdSelect);
cmdSelect = new APDUCmd(0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x44 }, 0x00);
cmdResponse = cardOri.Transmit(cmdSelect);
cmdSelect = new APDUCmd(0x00, 0xA4, 0x02, 0x00, new byte[] { 0x01, 0x01 }, 0x00);
cmdResponse = cardOri.Transmit(cmdSelect);
cmdSelect = new APDUCmd(0x00, 0xA4, 0x02, 0x00, new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02 }, 0x00);
cmdResponse = cardOri.Transmit(cmdSelect);
List<string> picData = new List<string>();
List<byte> picData1 = new List<byte>();
List<byte> picData2 = new List<byte>();
int j = 0x05;
int i = 0x00;
string sst = string.Empty;
int p1_first = 0x00;
int p2_first = 0x00;
int p1_end = 0x00;
int p2_end = 0x00;
int count = 0;

while (i <= 0x30)
{

    count++;
    try
    {

        cmdSelect = new APDUCmd(0x00, 0xB0, (byte)i, (byte)j, null, 0xFF);
        cmdResponse = cardOri.Transmit(cmdSelect);
        if (cmdResponse.Data != null)
        {
            picData1.AddRange(cmdResponse.Data);
        }
        else
        {
            p1_first = i - 1;
            p2_first = j + 1;

            byte[] ddd = null;
            while (true)
            {

                j--;
                cmdSelect = new APDUCmd(0x00, 0xB0, (byte)i, (byte)j, null, 0xFF);
                cmdResponse = cardOri.Transmit(cmdSelect);

                if (cmdResponse.Data != null)
                {
                    ddd = cmdResponse.Data;
                    picData2.AddRange(ddd);
                    p1_end = i;
                    p2_end = j;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    //  break;
                }
                if (j <= 0x00)
                {
                    i--;
                    j = 0xFF;
                }
            }
            break;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        DisConnect();
        break;
    }
    j = j + 0xFF;
    if (j > 0xFF)
    {
        i++;
        j = j - 0x100;
    }

}
int len = 0;
if (p1_first == p1_end)
{
    if (p2_first > p2_end)
    {
        len = 255 - (p2_first - p2_end);
    }
    else
    {
        len = 255 - (p2_end - p2_first);
    }
}
else
{
    if (p2_first > p2_end)
    {
        len = p2_first - p2_end - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        len = p2_end - p2_first - 1;
    }

}


int k = 0;
for (int l = len; l < 255; l++)
{
    picData1.Add(picData2[l]);
    k++;
}

File.WriteAllBytes("pic.txt", picData1);
```

Methods I tried:

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }

public bool ByteArrayToFile(string _FileName, byte[] _ByteArray)
    {
        try
        {
            System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(_FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
            _FileStream.Write(_ByteArray, 0, _ByteArray.Length);
            _FileStream.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception _Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", _Exception.ToString());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

How should I convert that byte arrey into an Image?

Answer (score 0):

If understood your question correctly you want get image from card reader to your pc then try this out

```
byte[] ArrayOfBytesOfYourImage= System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path); //Path your image file in sd card
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"Your path you want to save with extenction for example C:\Foo.jpeg", ArrayOfBytesOfYourImage);
```

if you dont have image but have only bytes. Then you dont need first 1st line.